# Limit access using ajax and .htaccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, .htaccess, request

I'va got a jquery file processing some mysql-data changes using ajax-calls (jQuery api) within php handler file.

This is my javascript:

```
$('#control1').click(function() {
    $('#control2').dialog({
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",
        width: "auto",
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: [
                  {
                      text: "Save",
                      click: function() {
                          $.ajax({
                             cache: false,
                             type: 'POST',
                             url: 'handler/some.handler.php',
                             data: $('#Form1').serialize(),
                             dataType: 'json',
                             beforeSend: function() {
                                 $('#Control3').fadeIn('fast');
                             },
                             success: function (data) {
                                 if (data.success) {
                                     alert(data.message);
                                     $(this).dialog("close");
                                     location.reload();
                                 } else {
                                     alert("Error occurred: " + data.message);
                                 }
                             },
                             error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                 alert("Error during process: " + thrownError);
                             },
                             complete: function () {
                                 $('#Control3').fadeOut('fast');
                             }
                          });
                      }
                  },
                  {
                      text: "Cancel",
                      click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
                  }
                  ]
    });
});
```

Inside the handler directory i placed a .htaccess file for managing file access and limit exception:

```
<LimitExcept GET POST HEAD>
    Order deny, allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

But Apache always return **500: Internal sever error**. If I delete the .htaccess file everything works fine... How to configure the .htaccess file correctly?

Thx!!!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve with that htaccess code in the first place? Either way, it could be that Apache doesn't like your `LimitExcept` statement because some module is not activated. Apache's Error logs would tell you more if you can access them

Comment: What does it show in your Apache Error Logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of dumb, but apache flips out if `Order` is given more than one parameter. You have a space in yours:

```
# here ----v
Order deny, allow
```

You just need to remove it:

```
Order deny,allow
```